# How to print to size Print coming out in a4 size

Tags: javascript, css

I need to print through receipt machine which are normally small.Problem is When i select print comes out on A4size,i want print to size.In print option when i select print to size then it is reduced to 5% and nothing is visible.My print code is

```
<div class="print_img">
 <button onclick="myFunction()">
    <div align="justify">Print</div>
 </button>   
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

<style>
 @media print {
    .print_img {
    display:none;
    }
}
```

What should i add in order to get correct print.My receipt looks like this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eugenenf/BVrh6/)

[Printer model](http://www.epson.co.in/epson_india/printers_and_all_in_ones/pos/product.page?product_name=Epson_TM-T81)

Comment: Cant you change it when you print window gets opened.

Comment: http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.in/2009/05/print-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print {
    .print_img {
        display:none;
    }
    @page{
        size:200px 400px;
    }
}
```

This would print a page with a width of 200px and height of 400px.